# using nameserver for redirection

Tags: hosting, redirect, web-hosting, nameserver, dns-hosting

I have bought a domain for cheap on crazydomains. The sad thing is they do not provide DNS settings without paying additional amount. They just give us a feature to set the nameserver details and some thing called 'Host records'.

**Is there any way to use the nameserver settings to redirect the domain to a blog address ?**

*And also is there any chance to avail free DNS services offered by many sites just by using the nameserver feature provided by Crazydomains ?*

Answer (score 1):

you can use the host records only to redirect to an IP.

If they provide a feature like hosting a single HTML file, you can use an HTTP redirect. For example, create an index.html File with the following content and adapt the URL in it to point to your blog:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://www.some-other-server.foo/some/path/to/your/blog.html"></head><body></body></html>
```

There are other options like a php-Redirect. Example:

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.exampledomain.foo/" );
?>
```

As long as you don't have your own Server to where you can point your IP to, this is the only way I can think of.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DNSEXIT it is free DNS service and you will get full control also dont forget to add NS record with your Domain Registrar.

Comment: Free DNS services tend to be less reliable than paid-for services.  Unsurprisingly.